# Solution of the given heat equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde, parabolic-pde

The steady state solution for the heat equation
$$
  \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}=0, \qquad 0<x<2, \quad t>0,
$$
with the initial condition
$$
  u(x,0)=0, \qquad 0<x<2,
$$
and the boundary conditions
$$
\begin{aligned}
  &u(0,t)=1,\\
  &u(2,t)=3, 
\end{aligned} \qquad t>0,
$$
at $x=1$ is

(A) $1$

(B) $2$

(C) $3$

(D) $4$

I tried to solve through separation of variables, but it is too difficult to determine the arbitrary constants from the given conditions. Again I have tried by using Laplace transformation, in this way at the final step, inverse Laplace formation is not good.

Any easiest way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Think about the physics of it. The left end is held at 1, the right end at 3. Things warm up in a complicated way but then eventually...what?

Comment: I guess the second-order partial derivative should be with respect to $x$. Please always double check before submitting a question. Finally. you have not shared any details about what you have tried to do. One last question, if you evaluate the PDE at its stationary solution, what do you get?

Comment: @KBS Yes. corrected.

Comment: @Paul +1. $\phantom{.}$

Comment: Paul's comment allows to find the answer almost without a calculation. As he said: think about physics. You are sitting in the middle of a room of which the wall temperatures at the left of you is $1$ and $3$ to your right. What is the temperature at your seat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, the steady-state solution $u_S$ is time-independent, hence $\dot{u}_S = 0$. In consequence, we have $u_S'' = 0$, which leads to $u_S(x) = Ax+B = x+1$, according to the boundary conditions. Finally, we get $u_S(1) = 2$.

Comment: Please refrain from posting solutions to exercises. OP could have been easily found the answer by using the hints given in comments.

Comment: I disagree. OP didn't know how to start, he tried separation of variables and Laplace transform by default, which led him nowhere. No comment recalls the time-independence of the steady-state solution (the main point to tackle this problem), but he's suggested to take an average, which seems arbitrary when one doesn't know that the answer is affine (which is not trivial, given the structure of the non-steady solution). I know that's an exercise, but my answer is short and goes to the point; there's no need to beat around the bush with an already condused student, apart from discouraging him.

Comment: My comment suggests to put the stationary solution in the equation, which was an attempt to make the OP realize that the partial derivative with respect to time goes away.